# border-radius округление

Tags: css3

Как в css с помощью border-radius написать 4 значений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По очереди устанавливает радиус для верхнего левого, верхнего правого, нижнего правого и нижнего левого уголка.

```css
.border{
border-radius: 10px 50px 90px 130px;
background-color: red;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
<br>
border-radius
<br> 
<br>
</div>
```

не понимаю что так сложно прогуглить атрибуты тега ?